# is there a way to to work with a switch with Radiobutton.IsChecked method?(C#)

Tags: c#, radio-button

i'm making something that should send an messagebox based on if some Radiobuttons are checked. So instead of using a lot of if's i thought shouldn't that be possible with a switch?
(it is in Dutch so don't mind the content and names)
this is the code I already have and I know that sender is wrong because it is triggered when clicked on a button.

```
private void berekenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton btn = sender as RadioButton;

    switch (btn.Name)
    {
        case "tussen18en30Radio":
            MessageBox.Show("je betaalt 15 euries");
                break;
        case "tussen30en45Radio":
            MessageBox.Show("je betaalt 10 euries ");
                break;
        case "tussen45en60":
            MessageBox.Show("je betaalt 10 euries");
            break;
        case"ouderdan60":
            MessageBox.Show("je betaalt 15 euries");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on your `switch` statement, what does it say `btn` is?  Your code looks like it should work (assuming the `btn` is a `RadioButton`

Comment: Are you saying you only want the messages to show if the radio button is checked, and right now it's displaying every time you click on a radio button regardless of whether that click is checking or unchecking it?

Comment: no I got Null Reference Exception at btn.Name but that is because my sender is an other button (no radioButton)

Comment: Could you please update your question with your XAML code? There are a few options for doing what you're asking but they can be dependent on whether your RadioButtons are marked up with a group, or inside a container, or any one of half a dozen other conditions.